# javascript take datetime input and filter list based on input

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an HTML webpage linked to two javascript files. One file contains the data (a list of dictionaries). The other javascript file is where I'm putting in the function of listing the data in a table - and filtering the table based on input. I've tried a few approaches by copying and pasting from examples online, but I don't know javascript well enough to get to a point where I can troubleshoot. I have two objectives I need help with:

**Objective 1:** How to have the input field on the site take in a search variable
**Objective 2:** How to take that search variable, and have it filter the table I'm displaying

Here is the important parts of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UFO Finder</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/superhero/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">UFO Sightings
            <img class="nav-ufo" src="static/images/ufo.svg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero text-center">
      <h1>UFO Sightings</h1>
      <p>The Truth is Out There</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row margin-top-50">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <aside class="filters">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Filter Search</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <ul class="list-group" id="filters">
                      <li class="filter list-group-item">
                        <label for="date">Enter a Date</label> <!-- this is where the input would come in on the page -->
                        <input class="form-control" id="datetime" type="text" placeholder="1/11/2011">
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div id="table-area" class="">
            <table id="ufo-table" class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="table-head">Date</th>
                  <th class="table-head">City</th>
                  <th class="table-head">State</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Country</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Shape</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Duration</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Comments</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <a href="filterButton">Filter Here!</a>  <!-- on click, this should trigger the filter table function-->
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <span class="bottom">UFO Sightings</span>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/data.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the javascript file with the function that puts in the file, along with the function that is currently NOT properly filtering the table:

```
// from data.js
var tbody = d3.select("tbody");
var submit = d3.select("#filterButton");

// on startup - this loads the full data table into the html page
function onStart() {
  data.forEach((toBeDefined) => {
    var row = tbody.append("tr");
    Object.entries(toBeDefined).forEach(([key,value]) => {
      var cell = tbody.append("td");
      cell.text(value);
    });
  });
}
onStart();

// this is the function I want to run when you click filter 
submit.on("click", function()  {      // I know this part is probably way off
  data.sort(function(o1,o2){          // this is just the last example I tried to 
    if (sort_o1_before_o2)    return -1;  // integrate into the code and gave up on
    else if(sort_o1_after_o2) return  1;  // just left it in for "structure"
    else                      return  0;
  });
})
```

And here is a sample of the `data.js` file so you can see how the data is structured.  I believe it is a list of dictionaries.

```
var data = [
  {
    datetime: "1/1/2010",
    city: "benton",
    state: "ar",
    country: "us",
    shape: "circle",
    durationMinutes: "5 mins.",
    comments: "4 bright green circles high in the sky going in circles then one bright green light at my front door."
  },
  {
    datetime: "1/1/2010",
    city: "bonita",
    state: "ca",
    country: "us",
    shape: "light",
    durationMinutes: "13 minutes",
    comments: "Three bright red lights witnessed floating stationary over San Diego New Years Day 2010"
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** Here is what you want

```js
// data.js
var data = [{
    datetime: "1/1/2010",
    city: "benton",
    state: "ar",
    country: "us",
    shape: "circle",
    durationMinutes: "5 mins.",
    comments: "4 bright green circles high in the sky going in circles then one bright green light at my front door."
  },
  {
    datetime: "1/1/2009",
    city: "bonita",
    state: "ca",
    country: "us",
    shape: "light",
    durationMinutes: "13 minutes",
    comments: "Three bright red lights witnessed floating stationary over San Diego New Years Day 2010"
  }];

// D3 selector
var tbody = d3.select("tbody");
var submit = d3.select("#filterButton");

// Update table with a new dataset
function updateTable(dataset) {
  tbody.html('');
  dataset.forEach((toBeDefined) => {
    var row = tbody.append("tr");
    Object.entries(toBeDefined).forEach(([key,value]) => {
      var cell = tbody.append("td");
      cell.text(value);
    });
  });
}

// Filter date function (just compare a string)
function filterByDate(dataset) {
    var filteredData = dataset.filter(function (d) {
      return d.datetime === $('#datetime').val();
    });
    return filteredData;
}

// Start here ...
// First update table of original data
updateTable(data); 
submit.on("click", function() {
  // When filter is click
  // Filter data by datetime and update the table
  var result = filterByDate(data);
  updateTable(result);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UFO Finder</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/superhero/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">UFO Sightings
            <img class="nav-ufo" src="static/images/ufo.svg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero text-center">
      <h1>UFO Sightings</h1>
      <p>The Truth is Out There</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row margin-top-50">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <aside class="filters">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Filter Search</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <ul class="list-group" id="filters">
                      <li class="filter list-group-item">
                        <label for="date">Enter a Date</label> <!-- this is where the input would come in on the page -->
                        <input class="form-control" id="datetime" type="text" placeholder="1/11/2011">
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div id="table-area" class="">
            <table id="ufo-table" class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="table-head">Date</th>
                  <th class="table-head">City</th>
                  <th class="table-head">State</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Country</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Shape</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Duration</th>
                  <th class="table-head">Comments</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <a id="filterButton">Filter Here!</a>  <!-- on click, this should trigger the filter table function-->
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <span class="bottom">UFO Sightings</span>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/data.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't see action with the new code.  My steps for taking in your answer was to: First: add the <script src....> portion to the HTML file.  Second:  comment out my original function that attempted to filter the table, and copied in your "function sortBy..." portion to the app.js file.  I'm still returning an error when I either click the "Filter Here!" button in the browser, or add the function name to the url.  Did I do something wrong?  Do you need more info?

Comment: Wouldn't trust passing that non ISO standard date string to `new Date` and expect consistent results cross environments

Comment: No problem @rgorowsky, I would suggest you may remove that clicking to filter. But add a `$('#datetime').on('keyup', function () {...});` instead. This will improve a lot of visualization, because it will update dynamically (whatever user typed).